# Springboot app in docker container unable to acquire JDBC connection after some time on one instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rest, jdbc

I'm experiencing a problem and have difficulty isolating the cause or even know where to look for it. I have a REST api service developed using Springboot and connected to a Postgres db and I run it on docker containers. There are multiple instances deployed, up to 10, all with the same configuration. After some time, say a few days, one of the instances will give these errors if you call any API that calls a JPA method that forms a connection to the database:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC connection...
... some long stack trace that eventually reaches this ...
```

This loops on forever until I manually restart the container, all the other instances work fine. I can ping the health endpoint of this instance via /actuator/health and the status will say 'UP'. If I deploy 4 instances, 1 of them throws this error, 3 of them continue working. If I have 10 instances, 1 will throw this error, 9 will continue to work. There are no alarming issues regarding memory or CPU usage. I have tried increasing memory, which doesn't help, the instances never use above ~450 mb of memory.
I thought that maybe connections are never being destroyed which will lead to preventing new connections to be formed. But that would not explain why the other instances can still operate normally after days/weeks+
Since this is only happening on one instance but nothing is giving me hints, I have trouble finding the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across something similar though not exactly as you describe it.

I was using entity manager to do some querying but the query was failing and i wasn't closing the connection on that entity manager, thus leaving the transaction hanging.

Are you testing on your local environment? If you do, install pg admin if you don't have it already and with the `Databases` selected, press on `Dashboard` and if something similar happens to you, you'll see it there. Also don't forget, while testing, to press the `refresh` button on the right side

[image: refresh button]

[image: dashboard]. I didn't see this at first and it took me some time to see what's going on